# Using Spring's RestTemplate with discovery service and external URLs too

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm working on a Spring REST microservice. The code uses RestTemplate to access other services. It's configured like this:

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Using this configuration the injected restTemplate instance would resolve service names specified in the domain and call the appropriate service. For example the following call would work: `restTemplate.getForEntity("http://service-name/...", ...);`

The problem is that we also want to use external services and use RestTemplate to query them.

For example `http://api.somedomain.com/...` would not work, the app would complain that the service `api.somedomain.com` is not known to the discovery service.

What makes this more interesting that in some cases the URL is unknown, so it's not known during development if the URL will contain a service name or a good old domain name, so the following code like `restTemplate.getForEntity(config.getURL(), ...);` should work regardless of what the URL contains. (which may come from config, DB, whatever)

The question is: Is it possible to configure RestTemplate to do so? What solutions can be to this problem?

The only thing I could think of is using a factory which returns an appropriate instance knowing the URL. The check would be simple and stupid: if the domain contains a dot, it's definitely not a service name. But that's something I'm trying to avoid at the moment.

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can create antoher Bean of RestTemplate without @LoadBalanced, like

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate externalRestTemplate(){
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And after that inject exactly this Bean like

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate externalRestTemplate;
```